# Disk is simply connected and the private disk of its center is not simply connected:

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

During my studies, I fell into a topological notion that I did not understand well, called simple connectedness. I went to see the definition (the one by homotopy), I found:

We say that a domain $D $ (a connected open set) is simply connected if any closed path $ \gamma $ included in $ D $  is homotopic to a point. On the other hand, if $ \gamma_1: [a, b] \to \mathbb{C}, t \to \gamma_1 (t)$, and $\gamma_2: [a, b] \to \mathbb {C}, t \to \gamma_2 (t)$ two closed paths defined on the same interval $[a, b],$ such that $\gamma_1 (a ) = \gamma_2 (a)$. We say that $\gamma_1 $ and $ \gamma_2 $ are homotopic in $ D \subset \mathbb {C} $ if there is a continuous application $ F: [a, b] \times [0, 1] \to D, (t, s) \to F (t, s), $ such that:
$$ F (t, 0) = \gamma_1 (t), \forall t \in [a, b], $$
$$ F (t, 1) = \gamma_2 (t), \forall t \in [a, b], $$
$$ F (a, s) = \gamma_1 (a) = \gamma_2 (a), \forall t \in [0, 1]. $$
My problem is to show that: a disk is simply connected and the private disk of its center is not simply connected:
For a $ D (z, r)$ disk with $ z \in \mathbb {C} $ and $ r> 0 $: $ D (z , r) $ is one more domain, if we take a closed path $\gamma $ defined on $ [a, b] $ and $ z_0 $ a point of this path (question: Is what I wrote correct? in other words, does the choice of $ z_0 $ belong to the chosen path?). Consider the continuous map $F: [a, b] \times [0, 1] \to D (z, r), (t, s) \to s \gamma (t) + (1-s) z_0 $, this function checks the homotopy assumptions, where $D (z, r) $ is simply connected.
But I have no idea to show that for the domain $ D (z, r) \setminus \{z \} $ is not just related. please what i tried to show correct? if not help me to better understand this notion?

Comment: Yes, the linear combination you defined is a correct homotopy. The problem for $D(z,r)\backslash\{z\}$ is a lot harder. It is typically done via algebraic topology (e.g. homology groups) or some functional analysis (e.g. Cauchy's integral theorem). You won't find such simple and straight-forward proof like in the full disk case. The punctured disk case requires lots of mathematical machinery.

Comment: OK thank you very much sir

Comment: What is a private disk?